# How to pass three js value to label in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project, i want three js values can be passed to label of div.Just like :

```
stWay:             stProposer:           stTime:
hello              John                  2017-09-07
```

I can click a button to make div1 appear successfully. But I can't get the value from js. The values of hello,John,2017-09-07 can't appear.

For the same format, i chosed set label css. So i don't want to use input.

Here is my js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   ......//click button to make div1 display block
   var reqStWay = "hello";
   var reqPeople = "John";
   var reqTime = "2017-09-07";
   $("#div1").css('display','block');
   $('#lblId').val(reqStWay);
   $('#lblId').val()=$('#lblId').val().appendto("         ");
   $('#lblId').val()=$('#lblId').val().appendto(reqPeople);
   $('#lblId').val()=$('#lblId').val().appendto("         ");
   $('#lblId').val()=$('#lblId').val().appendto(reqTime);
 }
</script>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<style>
.DIV1 label{.........}
</style>
<div id="div1" class="DIV1">
<label>stWay:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;stProposer:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;stTime:</label><br />
<label id="lblId"></label><br />
</div>
```

I also have tried

```
 $('#lblId').html(reqStWay"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"reqPeople"  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; "reqTime);
```

But unfortunately, it worked fail again. Who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to do it. Just modifying your version, you can get it working like this:

```
$('#lblId').html(reqStWay + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + reqPeople + "  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + reqTime);
```

Perhaps a cleaner way of achieving the same would be:

```
$('#lblId').append(reqStWay)
           .append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
           .append(reqPeople)
           .append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
           .append(reqTime);
```

Or we could do even better, like below. Just leaving it here in case someone runs into this question and seeks a better outlined HTML.

```js
var reqStWay = "hello";
var reqPeople = "John";
var reqTime = "2017-09-07";

$('#lblId').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+reqStWay+'</td><td>'+reqPeople+'</td><td>'+reqTime+'</td></tr>');
```

```css
#lblId td {
  padding:0 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="lblId">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>stWay</th>
      <th>stProsper</th>
      <th>stTime</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ,Thanks ,I chosed html()

Comment: In case you want to better format your text, I edited my answer.

Comment: @Aydin Your first line of code (`text()`) didn't work unless it is `html()`.

Comment: @JohnR - Agreed and amended. `text()` would not interpret the space characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#lblId').html(reqStWay + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + reqPeople + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " + reqTime);
```

This code works fine. You need `+` signs to concatenate strings. You did not have those.

Comment: It must be `+reqPeople+"  &nbsp;` not `+reqPeople"+  &nbsp;`